# Qt Kit Selection

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I recently installed Qt Creator on my Ubuntu machine using the command:

```
$ sudo apt install qtcreator
$ sudo apt install qt5-default
```

I also know that it is correctly installed through this

```
$ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

However, the Qt Creator app still does not let me select a Kit because my Qt Versions is
still empty:
[image: still empty]

It seems there are others with the same issue but I cannot find a solution.

Ultimately, this all began because I was trying to make a project after installing Qt but I could not get passed this Kit Selection:
[image: Kit Selection] menu. I learned that the kit selection problem stems from not having the "Qt version" installed. However, I still cannot find a solution to how I can correctly install this Qt version.

Answer (score 0):

you should install gcc and g++ compiler, look at [Qt documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu)

you should write this command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

> Launch Qt Creator. Go to Tools > Options. Click Build & Run and select
> tab Kit. Configure a compiler if it is not automatically detected.

this problem happens because of qt creator didn't understand and find the compiler, you should install it, after that it is usually automatically detected. if you have this issue again you should add it manually in the compiler section and in the kit section set compiler for your Desktop kit.

For adding manually **compiler** look at [this QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html)

For adding manually **kit** look at [this QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)

**For Adding Qt Versions manually**

look at [this QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html)

To add a Qt version:

1. Select Tools > Options > Kits > Qt Versions > Add.
2. Select the qmake executable for the Qt version that you want to add.
3. Select the Qt version to view and edit it.
4. In the Version name field, edit the name that Qt Creator suggests
   for the Qt version.
5. In the qmake location field, you can change the qmake location.
6. If the Qt version is for QNX, enter the path to your installed QNX
   SDK in the QNX SDK field.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I've already installed build-essential as well. GCC also is already installed in my system, as I already compile c++ with it.

Comment: I always install qt by .run file or source code , try second way that doc tells because by this way that you write qt5-default you should install modules separately

Comment: For example if you want charts , you should again install it and so on . And you should use version that os find , for example for ubuntu 18.04 default version is qt 5.9

Comment: look at [this](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/) site choose one version of qt , I recommend Qt 5.12 because it is stable. and for Linux download `.run` file and after download finished, you should `chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.0.run` and then run it by `./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.0.run` . (by this way a wizard appears for you ) and will be installed in home . and then qtcreator autodetact it